# What does //# mean and do?

Tags: javascript

I've found some code with this in it, //# what does it mean or do? Any kind of documents or guidance on it would be much appreciated because I've looked around and can't really find it.

I've tried googling it and searching the web.

Comment: `//` is used for single line comments in JavaScript. The # character is part of the comment.

Comment: There are some contexts where `//` comments at the start of a line may be interpreted as some sort of metadata for build purposes (or other similar things), but without having more context about where you encountered the comment, it's impossible to say more than that.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a syntax to map to a source map file, according to [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps#how_does_the_source_map_work) from Google, and [this guide](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/use_a_source_map/index.html) from Mozilla

Comment: This is true, though the OP did not include the actual line of code that started with that notation so we don't really know what it was.